# Getting total combinations of diagonal or horizontal line combinations based on user input of heights JAVA

Tags: java, for-loop

I am presented with a problem where I need to take user input, and return all combinations of any 3 heights that when put in order from smallest to greatest results in a diagonal or horizontal line. For example, if the user input is 3 5 7 10 2 1 1 1, then the output should be

```
1 1 1
1 2 3
1 3 5
3 5 7
```

I have some working code, but my issue is getting results that are greater distances than 1 apart. My current working code so far is as follows.

```
    Arrays.sort(intArray);
    int counter = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < intArray.length - 2; x++){
        if(intArray[x] == intArray[x+1] && intArray[x] == intArray[x+2] && intArray[x] != 0){
            validArray[counter][0] = intArray[x];
            validArray[counter][1] = intArray[x+1];
            validArray[counter][2] = intArray[x+2];
            counter++;
        }
        if(intArray[x] < intArray[x+1]){
            dif = intArray[x+1] - intArray[x];
            if(dif == intArray[x+2] - intArray[x+1]){
                validArray[counter][0] = intArray[x];
                validArray[counter][1] = intArray[x+1];
                validArray[counter][2] = intArray[x+2];
                counter++;
            }
        }

    }
    for(int x = 0; x < validArray.length; x++){
        if(validArray[x][0] != 0){
            System.out.println(validArray[x][0] + " " + validArray[x][1] + " " + validArray[x][2]);
        }
    }
```

If the user inputs 3 5 7 10 2 1 1 1
I get

```
1 1 1
1 2 3
3 5 7
```

and not 1 3 5. I understand why my code is not outputting the correct output, but I am not sure of how to go about coding my loop structure to get the desired output. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by combinations of "3 heights"? Do you mean that the rows should be 3 wide? And should the numbers be in ascending order on vertical lines too (you only mention diagonal and horizontal)?

Comment: The user input is a height. So 3 5 10 2 1 are all heights of lets say a pole. Using any 3 poles, I need to find all combinations where if you put them in order, the height of Pole 1, Pole 2 and Pole 3 are either a) equal, or b) in ascending order where P3-P2 == P2 - P1 such that P1 < P2 < P3

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you evaluate all possible triplets using nested for-loops, for example:

```
Arrays.sort(intArray);
final int len = intArray.length;
ArrayList<int[]> validComb = new ArrayList<int[]>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1 ; j < len ; j++) {
        for(int k = j+1 ; k < len ; k++) {
            int[] comb = {intArray[i], intArray[j], intArray[k]};

            if(/*comb is valid*/ && /*comb is not a duplicate of another combination*/) {
                validComb.add(comb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed! I was having a hard time wrapping my head around the logic.

Comment: @Maljam Even though solution is correct the `validComb` will contain only the last solution. `com` is an array so it won't be copied while insertion. So let's say you inserted [1,1,1] solution. In next iteration you assign let's say [1,1,2] to `comb`. The [1,1,1] inside the list will change.

Comment: @Julian, oops you're right, I was trying to maximise readability... thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 1):

Varation of Maljam solution. After checking horizontal line we can skip other same numbers. Moreover instead of third nested `for` we can use `binarySearch` from `Arrays` class. `addLine` is a method which adds triple passed as an argument to result set. It doesn't produce duplicates as well.

```
for(int x = 0; x < input.length - 2; x++) {

    if(input[x] == input[x + 1]
       && input[x] == input[x + 2]
       && input[x] != 0)
       addLine(input[x], input[x + 1], input[x + 2]);

    while(x < input.length - 1 && input[x] == input[x + 1])
       x++;

    if(x >= input.length - 2)
        break;

    for(int y = x + 1; y < input.length - 1; y++) {
        int dif = input[y] - input[x];
        int matching = binarySearch(input, y + 1,
            input.length, input[y] + dif);
        if(matching > 0)
            addLine(input[x], input[y], input[matching]);
    }
}
```